# Send email through Gmail under Administrator Profile

Tags: email, gmail

We are using Lightning Experience. We have a single user license and it has the administrator profile. We want to send emails through Gmail.

We have completed the setup following these instructions from (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_enable_send_through_external.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

1. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Send through External Email
   Services, and then select Send through External Email Services.
2. Select either Send through Gmail or Send through Office 365.
3. From Setup, enter Deliverability in the Quick Find box, then select
   Deliverability under Email.
4. Set the access level for sending email to All email.

We are still unable to send emails via Gmail. All emails are still going from salesforce.

It appears that there is another step involved at a user level (https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/07/03/email-from-salesforce-2/)
When the user tries to send the next email, an option to select the option should appear. We don't see that.

Also, we don't think "Send Email Through Email Relay" is relevant in this case. That's for companies with their own domain/SMTP servers, etc.

Appreciate any pointers you can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Salesforce support and they were able to resolve it.

We had to turn off Einstein Activity Capture. This resolved the issue. You cannot have Einstein Activity Capture and send through Gmail active at the same time. It has to be one or the other.

The good news is I can send individual emails via Gmail. The bad news is, list email does not have this feature. It will still be sent via Salesforce.